# Rails 3.1 / Active Admin / Heroku error on first load - Sass::SyntaxError

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

When hitting the app without any activity for a while, it throws the following error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError (File to import not found or unreadable: active_admin/mixins.
```

If I refresh the page, it loads perfectly without any errors.

Is this a Heroku issue or a real app error? Anyone know of any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you have a Sass syntax error that the asset pipeline is dealing with during compile.  The reason for it only happening after inactivity is that the app is idled down by Heroku and needs to restart to serve a request, hence the asset pipeline 'waking up' again.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the   gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0" from the group set.

Comment: It's not just about this gem, my guess is that any gem that lists sass-rails as a dependency will contribute to this issue. Putting all these related gems into the assets group should make things work well. I was including the animate-sass gem outside of the assets group, and that gave me the error.

Comment: How does one remove the gem from the group set? What group set? How does one specify an assets group?

Comment: Do you know the gem file? All you need to remove the gem from group :assets do

Answer (score 1):

add a sass_heroku.rb to config/initializers and it should do the trick

```
heroku = !!ENV['HEROKU_TYPE']
css_dir = heroku ? 'tmp' : 'public'
location = Rails.root + 'app/styles'

unless Sass::Plugin.template_location_array.any? { |pair| pair.first.to_s == location.to_s }
    Sass::Plugin.add_template_location(location, Rails.root + css_dir + 'stylesheets')
end

if heroku
  Sass::Plugin.template_location_array.each do |template_location, css_location|
    css_location.sub!(%r{/public/stylesheets$}, "/#{css_dir}/stylesheets")
  end
  Rails.configuration.middleware.insert_after 'Sass::Plugin::Rack', 'Rack::Static', :urls => ['/stylesheets'], :root => "#{Rails.root}/tmp"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried several things to no avail. I tried precompiling locally and on Heroku.

When I hit my Heroku site, I get...

```
ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: active_admin/mixins.
2012-08-01T22:00:22+00:00 app[web.2]: Load paths:
2012-08-01T22:00:22+00:00 app[web.2]:   /app
2012-08-01T22:00:22+00:00 app[web.2]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/app/assets/stylesheets
2012-08-01T22:00:22+00:00 app[web.2]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss)):
2012-08-01T22:00:22+00:00 app[web.2]:     6:   <title><%= [@page_title, active_admin_application.site_title].compact.join(" | ") %></title>
2012-08-01T22:00:22+00:00 app[web.2]:     7: 
2012-08-01T22:00:22+00:00 app[web.2]:     8:   <% ActiveAdmin.application.stylesheets.each do |style| %>
2012-08-01T22:00:22+00:00 app[web.2]:     9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag style.path, style.options %>
2012-08-01T22:00:22+00:00 app[web.2]:     10:   <% end %>
2012-08-01T22:00:22+00:00 app[web.2]:     11:   <% ActiveAdmin.application.javascripts.each do |path| %>
2012-08-01T22:00:22+00:00 app[web.2]:     12:     <%= javascript_include_tag path %>
2012-08-01T22:00:22+00:00 app[web.2]:   app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss:2
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried Stephane Paul's solution, even though I'm not smart enough to understand it - didn't help.

What solved the problem for me was pre-compiling ahead of time.

Just to clarify, I've only seen this error when trying to use activeadmin on Heroku - worked fine in development.

And the solution was to run `rake assets:precompile` and make sure to git commit the public/assets directory to heroku, which will then not precomiple the assets itself, hence the error will be skipped.